# Bind function to multiple events of different elements at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to bind a function to the `mouseout` event of my `<canvas>` element, and bind the same function to the `blur` and `contextmenu` events of my body. How would I go about binding this function to those elements at once, when there are **different elements** which need the same function bound to **different events of each**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Define your function beforehand:

```
function eventHandler(event) {}
```

and assign it separately:

```
$('canvas').mouseout(eventHandler);
$('body').bind('blur contextmenu', eventHandler);
```

With [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) you can at least bind one event handler to **multiple events**.

Comment: Yes I discovered that already, but using the 3 events to the 2 elements will e.g. also bind the function to the body's onmouseout event etc. But this will do, thanks.

Comment: @pimvdb: There is no other way. If you select both, `canvas` and body, then how can jQuery know which event to bind which element? It is just not possible.

Comment: No, of course, so I asked for a possible way, but I understand there just isn't any. I'll just bind the function separately.