# Jquery combine click and change for one execution

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind function to multiple events of different elements at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805818/bind-function-to-multiple-events-of-different-elements-at-once)

I need to execute the same code for both a link click and change event

```
$(".foo").click(function() {

  //same code

}

$(".bar").change(function() {

  //same code

}
```

The normal way I would achieve is to create a function and then fire the function on each seperate event - but I'm wondering if jquery has an easier way to handle this, similar to

```
 $(".bar, .foo").
```

But obviously with different event methods.

To clarify i need one to click and one to change but NOT both to click and change, does that make sense?

Comment: Defining a function (e.g. `foo`) and doing `$('.foo').click(foo); $('.bar').change(foo)` is the most DRY you can get with jQuery in this scenario (and there's nothing wrong with that).

Comment: @Matt that is equivalent to `$(".foo,.bar").on("click change", foo)`, isn't it? And that's what neal had from the start

Comment: @Esailija: No, because the `foo` element doesn't have a `change` handler bound to it, and vice versa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(".foo, .bar").on("click change", function(e){

    var myClass = $(this).is(".foo") ? "foo" : "bar";

    if(e.type === "change"){
         //DO STUFF UNIQUE TO CHANGE
    }
    else if(e.type === "click") {
         //DO STUFF UNIQUE TO CLICK
    }

    //DO STUFF THAT IS THE SAME

});
```

Comment: ... but then `bar` will have a `click` event on it...

Comment: @Matt that is what the OP wants ^_^

Comment: yep, thanks matt was about to say that, i need to avoid the click event firing for one of them

Comment: The pursuit of clarity is not always easy!