# Multiple jquery events with same execution - how to combine?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I've found many threads on combining click and change jquery events. But I'm not sure how to combine a basic click event with this specific event for Bootstrap Switch. The following two events should have the same code. What is the best way to combine them, so I don't have repeat the same code twice?

1.

```
$('#regular-product .cancel').click(function(e){

   // SAME CODE GOES HERE //

});
```

2.

```
$('#regular-product .toggle').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {

    if ($('#regular-product .bootstrap-switch').hasClass('bootstrap-switch-off')) {

      // SAME CODE GOES HERE //

    }       
});
```

Here is an answer I found that I wasn't able to repeat for this. ([Jquery combine click and change for one execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470879/jquery-combine-click-and-change-for-one-execution)) Perhaps it's not the right method in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code into a function.

E.g.:

```
var myHandler = function()  {
  // do here some stuff you want to
};
$('#regular-product .cancel').click(myHandler);
$('#regular-product .toggle').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', myHandler);
```

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense -- I was thinking about it backwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly but I suggest to just define a javascript function which evaluates your code and call that function in both cases.