# Jquery bind user defind function with different elements

Tags: jquery

```
$("#mySecondDiv").bind('my-event', function(event, a ,b) { /* ... */ });
$("#mySecondDiv").trigger('my-event', [1, 2]);
```

Here is a function defined inside `bind()` method .  I want this function to be once defined globally and use for multiple elements.

For example :

```
function{ //definition }

$("#mySecondDiv").bind('my-event', --call above function here--);
$("#mySecondDiv").trigger('my-event', [1, 2]);

$("#myAnotherDiv").bind('my-event', --again call the same above function here--);
$("#myAnotherDiv").trigger('my-event', [1, 2]);
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: `function foo() {...} $(...).bind('click', foo);` Learn more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html

Comment: *similar*: [Bind function to multiple events of different elements at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805818/bind-function-to-multiple-events-of-different-elements-at-once) ... note that in your case you can simply both elements at once though `$('#id1, #id2').bind(...)`.

Comment: If You are using the jQuery lib version 1.7 or above then try `.on()` instead of `.bind()` as it is  outdated method. **jQuery Ref:** *As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.*

Answer (score 2):

Thats quiet easy

**JS CODE:**

```
function callMultiple () { //definition }

$("#mySecondDiv").bind('my-event', callMultiple);
$("#mySecondDiv").trigger('my-event', [1, 2]);

$("#myAnotherDiv").bind('my-event', callMultiple);
$("#myAnotherDiv").trigger('my-event', [1, 2]);
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: You can also access the unlisted function parameters inside the function definition by using the 'arguments' array.

Comment: It's not working, and I also have to pass some object in this function. Kindly tell me with parameterised function.

Comment: @Ali: Kindly explain what exactly "is not working" and provide a better example for your requirements. If you don't provide the necessary information, it is very difficult for us to help you. Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TcJWs/.

Answer (score 0):

Define your function somewhere -

`function yourFunction(event, a ,b) { /* ... */ }`

Now you can use it this way -

```
$("#mySecondDiv").bind('my-event', yourFunction);
$("#myAnotherDiv").bind('my-event', yourFunction);
```

Comment: $("#mySecondDiv").bind('populate', yourFunction);
$("#myAnotherDiv").trigger('populate');

function{
//code here
}

I just have written this, but it's not working.

Comment: @AliShahzad , You need to trigger event

Comment: @AliShahzad: I guess its not related to external functional reference, its something else which would be causing problem :) just a create a jsfiddle, so that it will be easy to rectify your problem. fiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Ali: If you exactly wrote what you put in your comment, then you have a syntax error. `function{ //code here }` is not valid JavaScript.